# Modal component in VueJS

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I am building a web app. I have few components that are modals (that show data about customers, lessons, ...).
I search a way to show one of the components easily. 
And if possible doing lazy loading.
What's the best way to perform this?

Comment: Nobody will really be able to help you with this without you specifying what you have tried so far and what you want to accomplish. What do you mean with showing a component "easily"? What is not easy about how you do it now? How are you opening a modal now? Imagine you don't have your code in front of you and see a question like yours.. how would you answer it?

Answer (score 1):

Check out conditional rendering, specifically v-if. This would only load the modal if the button is clicked for example.

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/conditional.html#v-if

Single page component:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div
      v-if="showModal"
      class="modal">
      Stuff
    </div>
    <button @click="toggleModal">
      Toggle Modal
    </button>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    data () {
      return {
        showModal: false
      }
    },
    methods: {
      toggleModal() {
        this.showModal = !this.showModal
      }
    },
  }
</script>
```